# Using Kafka Producer by different threads

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have kafka producer for my java based web application to push messages to Kafka. As per the documentation I could see kafka producer is thread safe. Does it mean that I can have single instance of Kafka producer and use it by different threads ( web requests ) each will open and close the producer in my case. Will this create any issues ? Or Is better to initiate Producers per request ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, KafkaProducer is threadsafe.
Refer to [Class KafkaProducer](https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html)

> A Kafka client that publishes records to the Kafka cluster.
>
> The producer is thread safe and should generally be shared among all
>   threads for best performance.
>
> The producer manages a single background thread that does I/O as well
>   as a TCP connection to each of the brokers it needs to communicate
>   with. Failure to close the producer after use will leak these
>   resources.

Comment: I am worndering if it handle the below scenario..
One thread opens a producer and before sending data another thread closes it . Will there be exception when execute send by first thread?

Comment: absolutely exception is thrown. usually we use micro-container like spring context, and close kafka consumer only when destroying spring context.

Comment: If only has one instance of `KafkaProducer` then where and how can we call `close` method on it?

Comment: Is this also true for the new transactional APIs? The documentation doesn't specify, and I'm seeing behavior that indicates it is not safe.

Comment: @Raman i had the same questionI. think for multi-threaded case with transactions, a ThreadLocal Producer with unique transactionId for each producer should be used

Comment: @AshikaUmangaUmagiliya yes I concluded that the transactional APIs are not thread-safe. I actually find the design of them poorly done -- they assume a certain consumer threading context which could have been avoided with the use of transaction handles.

Answer (score 3):

By far the best approach (which is typical of most stateful clients connectors, eg SQL clients, elasticsearch client, etc) is to instantiate a single instance at application start and share it across all threads. It should only be closed on application shutdown.

Comment: Hello, I'm beginning in java and I'm wondering how to do such things, do you have any examples I could look at? thanks